# Migrating Workflow Foundation to Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, workflow-foundation, visual-studio-2019

I am in the process of migrating to VS 2019 but have an issue when opening a solution that contains a Workflow Foundation project.

On loading a Visual Studio 2019 the project will not load and just states; "needs migration" next to the project name in Solution Explorer.

I have followed the steps detailed in this article [[Here]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/workflow-designer/developing-applications-with-the-workflow-designer?view=vs-2019) but to no avail.

Answer (score 7):

I've had the same problem and the solution was to install Office/Sharepoint development workload from the Visual Studio Installer. 
If there will be still some issues, you may try to open solution in Visual Studio 2017 (Some parts of Workflow are no longer supported in VS 2019 )

Comment: That worked for me too.  The project failed to load until the Visual Studio option for Office was installed using the Visual Studio installer.